# How to have an element with a click event that only works if the element is visible on screen?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I have an element with an `@click` attribute that clicks a different element on screen like this:

```
<div class="card" @click="$refs.detailsLink.$el.click()">
```

And `$refs.detailsLink` refers to this element:

```
<div class="hidden-mobile">
    <MyLink :id="$id('view-details')"
        ref="viewDetailsLink">
    </MyLink>
</div>
```

And `hidden-mobile` is a CSS style that is a part of a media query for mobile devices and simply makes the display be none:

```
  .hidden-mobile {
    display: none;
  }
```

**The Problem:**
The problem is that when `<MyLink>` is hidden because it is a mobile device, the user can still click the card that contains `<MyLink>` and trigger the on click event.

So what can I do to this `<div class="card" @click="$refs.detailsLink.$el.click()">` that checks if the element is even visible and if it is not, then don't triggers the click event.

Comment: I think you could make the `hidden-mobile` added to the div using a js (if screen size < threshold), not using media query, so on the card handler, you could add a condition if screen size < threshold, then don't execute `$refs.detailsLink.$el.click()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `if else statements` like that:

```js
var elementId = document.getElementById('view-details');
if (elementId.style.display === 'none') {
    // do this
} else {
    // do that
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your click handler check and see if the display of the link is none.

I'm not sure what framework you're using, but I'm assuming there is some sort of reference to the element that was clicked, so just get that element and check its classList.

Comment: Im using Vue and I dont have any other click handler other than what you see. `$refs.detailsLink.$el.click()` will click <MyLink>

Comment: I'm not really familiar with Vue, however I do see there is a `$refs.detailsLink.$el` which seems to be a reference to the element (again I'm not really sure). Check and see if `$refs.detailsLink.$el` has the `classList` property attached to it.

Comment: @justanotherguy seems to me that `hidden-mobile` class is always attached because he mentions he uses media query, that way he can't really detect if the ref exists by checking the classList

Comment: Thats exactly right @Damzaky

Comment: I can't provide the code since you don't provide the full code, but basically you could use something like `@click="handler"`, then inside the `handler` add `if (!window.matchMedia("(max-width: 780px)"))`  then `this.$refs.detailsLink.$el.click()`, else `// do nothing`